# Why are some button elements not displayed?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Two of the "decrement" buttons are not displayed and have been highlighted yellow in VScode IDE. What's going wrong?

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Increment and Decrement counter</h1>

  <div>

    <button onclick="increment()">+</button>
    <h2 id="counting">h2 tag</h2>
    <button onclick="decrement()">-</button>
    <button onclick="decrement()">-</button>
    <button onclick="decrement()">-</button>
    <button onclick="decrement()">-</button>
    <button onclick="decrement()">-</button>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried as a snippet in Stack and it was OK. Try to restart vsCode

Comment: @Dai OP's question is `Why first and third '-' button does not show as a button in html part`

Comment: Also I tried in vsCode and everything was OK too

Comment: Try checking in inspect element to know the CSS properties are applied or not.. Or some other CSS is overriding it

Comment: The issue might seem unreproducible if [no-break spaces are turned into normal spaces after copy & paste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135608/no-break-spaces-are-turned-into-normal-spaces-after-copy-paste).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is related to [NO-BREAK SPACE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) characters in the first and third "decrement" buttons:

[image]

(from https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php)

My browser interprets them like this:

```
<button&nbsp;onclick="decrement()">-
<button onclick="decrement()">-</button>
<button&nbsp;onclick="decrement()">-
<button onclick="decrement()">-</button>
<button onclick="decrement()">-</button>
```

Resulting in this invalid structure:

[image]

When I replace those characters with a normal space, the issue is resolved.

Before:

```html
<button onclick="decrement()">-</button>
<button onclick="decrement()">-</button>
<button onclick="decrement()">-</button>
<button onclick="decrement()">-</button>
<button onclick="decrement()">-</button>
```

After:

```html
<button onclick="decrement()">-</button>
<button onclick="decrement()">-</button>
<button onclick="decrement()">-</button>
<button onclick="decrement()">-</button>
<button onclick="decrement()">-</button>
```

Also see:
[What is this INSANE space character??? (google chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962323/what-is-this-insane-space-character-google-chrome)